# Split CSV to Multiple Files Containing a Set Number of Unique Field Values

Tags: csv, awk, split, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

As a beginner of `awk` I am able to split the data with unique value by

`awk -F, '{print >> $1".csv";close($1)}' myfile.csv`

But I would like to split a large CSV file based on additional condition which is the occurrences of unique values in a specific column.

Specifically, with input

```
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1
444,1,1,1
444,0,0,0
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0
```

I would like the output files to be

```
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1
```

and

```
444,1,1,1
444,1,0,1
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0
```

each of which contains *three*(in this case) unique values, `111,222,333`and `444,555,666`respectively, in first column. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what the condition for splitting the file is.

Comment: do you mean 3 uniq values per file?

Comment: yes, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick and I find it pretty readable and easy to understand:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { count=0; filename=1 }
            x[$1]++==0 {count++}
            count==4 { count=1; filename++}
            {print >> filename".csv"; close(filename".csv");}' file
```

We start with our count at 0 and our filename at 1. We then count each unique value we get from the fist column, and whenever its the 4th one, we reset our count and move to the next filename.

Here's some sample data I used, which is just yours with some additional lines.

```
~$ cat test.txt
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1
444,1,1,1
444,0,0,0
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0
777,1,1,1
777,1,0,1
777,1,1,0
777,1,1,1
888,1,0,1
888,1,1,1
999,1,1,1
999,0,0,0
999,0,0,1
101,0,0,0
102,0,0,0
```

And running the awk like so:

```
~$ awk -F',' 'BEGIN { count=0; filename=1 }
            x[$1]++==0 {count++}
            count==4 { count=1; filename++}
            {print >> filename".csv"; close(filename".csv");}' test.txt
```

We see the following output files and content:

```
~$ cat 1.csv
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1

~$ cat 2.csv
444,1,1,1
444,0,0,0
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0

~$ cat 3.csv
777,1,1,1
777,1,0,1
777,1,1,0
777,1,1,1
888,1,0,1
888,1,1,1
999,1,1,1
999,0,0,0
999,0,0,1

~$ cat 4.csv
101,0,0,0
102,0,0,0
```

Comment: As you said, I understand the code once I read it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner would help:

```
awk -F, -v u=3 -v i=1 '{a[$1];
   if (length(a)>u){close(i".csv");++i;delete a;a[$1]}print>i".csv"}' file
```

You change the `u=3` value into `x` to gain `x` unique values per file.

If you run this line with your input file, you should got `1.csv and 2.csv`

### Edit (add some test output):

```
kent$  ll
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 kent kent  60 Mar 25 18:19 ./
drwxrwxrwt 19 root root 580 Mar 25 18:18 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 kent kent  90 Mar 25 17:57 f

kent$  cat f
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1
444,1,1,1
444,0,0,0
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0

kent$  awk -F, -v u=3 -v i=1 '{fn=i".csv";a[$1];if (length(a)>u){close(fn);++i;delete a;a[$1]}print>fn}' f  

kent$  head *.csv
==> 1.csv <==
111,1,0,1
111,1,1,1
222,1,1,1
333,1,0,0
333,1,1,1

==> 2.csv <==
444,1,1,1
444,0,0,0
555,1,1,1
666,1,0,0
```