# AWK: Ignore lines grouped by an unique value conditioned on occurrences of a specific field value

Tags: awk, split, pattern-matching, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

Please help revise the title and the post if needed, thanks.

In short, I would like to firstly group lines with a unique value in the first field and accumulate the occurrences of a specific value in the other field in the underlying group of lines. If the sum of occurrences doesn't meet the self-defined threshold, the lines in the group should be ignored.

Specifically, with input

```
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,0
111,1,M,1
222,1,M,1
222,1,M,0
333,1,P,0
333,1,P,1
444,1,M,1
444,1,M,1
444,0,M,0
555,1,P,1
666,1,P,0
```

the desired output should be

```
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,0
111,1,M,1
333,1,P,0
333,1,P,1
555,1,P,1
666,1,P,0
```

meaning that "because the unique values in the first field `222` and `444` don't have at least *one* (which can be any desired threshold) `P` in the third field, lines corresponding to `222` and `444` are ignored."

Furthermore, this should be done without editing the original file and have to be combined with the solved issue [Split CSV to Multiple Files Containing a Set Number of Unique Field Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261265/split-csv-to-multiple-files-containing-a-set-number-of-unique-field-values). By doing this, a few lines will not be involved in the resulted split files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this one-liner does what you want:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1,++c[$1]]=$0}$3=="P"{p[$1]}END{for(i in c)if(i in p)for(j=1;j<=c[i];++j)print a[i,j]}' file
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,1
111,1,P,0
111,1,M,1
333,1,P,0
333,1,P,1
555,1,P,1
666,1,P,0
```

Array `a`, keeps track of all the lines in the file, grouping them by the first field and a count `c` which we use later. If the third field contains a P, set a key in the `p` array.

After processing the entire file, loop through all the values of the first field. If a key has been set in `p` for the value, then print the lines from `a`.

You mention a threshold number of entries in your question. If by that, you mean that there must be `N` occurrences of "P" in order for the lines to be printed, you could change `{p[$1]}` to `{++p[$1]}`, then change `if(i in p)` to `if(p[i]>=N)` in the `END` block.